# How to display highest and lowest of an array

Tags: c#, arrays

here i ask the user for homework scores which are then averaged after discarding the smallest and largest score. i have stored the user input in an array. in my DisplayResults method im not sure how to display the lowest and highest scores that were discarded. any help is appreciated! Here is what i have so far:

```
class Scores
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        int arraySize;
        double[] inputValues;

        arraySize = HowManyScores();

        inputValues = new double[arraySize];
        GetScores(inputValues);
        sum = CalculateSum(inputValues);
        average = CaculateAverage(sum, arraySize);

        DisplayResults(inputValues, average);
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static int HowManyScores()
    {
        string input;
        int size;
        Console.WriteLine("How many homework scores would you like to enter?");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        while (int.TryParse(input, out size) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid data. Please enter a numeric value.");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return size;
    }

    public static void GetScores(double[] inputValues)
    {
        double scoreInput;
        Console.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < inputValues.Length; i++)
        {
            scoreInput = PromptForScore(i + 1);
            inputValues[i] = scoreInput;
        }
    }

    public static double PromptForScore(int j)
    {
        string input;
        double scoreInput;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter homework score #{0}:", j);
        input = Console.ReadLine();

        while (double.TryParse(input, out scoreInput) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Data. Your homework score must be a numerical value.");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        while (scoreInput < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Data. Your homework score must be between 0 and 10.");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        while (scoreInput > 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Data. Your homework score must be between 0 and 10.");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return scoreInput;
    }

    public static double CalculateSum(double[] inputValues)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < inputValues.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            sum += inputValues[i];
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public static double CaculateAverage(double sum, int size)
    {
        double average;
        average = sum / ((double)size - 2);
        return average;
    }

    public static void DisplayResults(double[] inputValues, double average)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Average homework score: {0}", average);

        //Console.WriteLine("Lowest score that was discarded: {0}",
        //Console.WriteLine("Highest score that was discarded: {0}",
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can use the `.Min`, `.Max` (and also `.Average`) methods for your `inputValues` array. Basically `Console.WriteLine(inputValues.Max());` will produce the maximum value in your array.

Comment: Your code is "discarding" two scores, but I don't see anything that would ensure that the scores being discarded are in fact the lowest and highest scores. That said, if you understand how the code is discarding values, it seems to me it should be clear how to actually retrieve those scores which have been discarded. What _specifically_ seems to be the problem here? I'll note that the scores are more "disregarded" than "discarded". I.e. they remain in the original array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically only have to do one thing: Sorting the array after you received your input data. Then, printing the first and last value gives you the minimal and maximal score. Use

```
Array.Sort(intArray);
```

in `main` after calling `GetScores` and

```
 Console.WriteLine("Lowest score: {0} Highest score: {1}", 
    inputValues[0], inputValues[inputValues.Length - 1]);
```

to print the results. Cheers

**EDIT:** The proposal by Jens from the comments using the Min/Max is probably more what you're looking for if you're not interested in complete ordering of your values.

Comment: Given that the original question is a homework assignment, a _good_ answer would provide more specific details about why the above addresses the question. Simply doing their homework for them isn't helping them.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes, you're right, I didn't consider that. However, there seems to be little difference between giving a hint and solving the problem in this case

Comment: But there is a big difference between walking them through the solution and just handing it to them.

Comment: I did write the entire code here.. (no ones doing my homework).. sometimes you get stuck, I dont need to be walked through a simple answer.. its pretty self explanatory.

Comment: I think the Array.Sort may work better as that will put all my values in order and discard the lowest and highest, something I had not written into the code. thanks again!